# Whether the sqlchemy engine created in the class attribute is the same

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have a class like this

```py
from sqlalchemy import create_engine


class MyModel:
    engine = create_engine('sqlite:///example.db')
```

I want to know if I use this class in two other python files, whether the engine in the two pythons is the same

I have tried importing two other python files "A" and "B" from A to B and judging by is. The result is true, but I think it is not rigorous enough.
I think it should probably be false

Comment: I asked chatgpt and it told me it was true

Comment: The class definition in your code is executed when the module is first imported, so the engine will be the same for all instances of the class.